# Is there a conversion utility for converting NMAKE build files to CMAKE build files?

Tags: cmake, nmake, file-conversion

Or are you all laughing so hard that you can't type a response? :)

Bottom line is that one library we're using (GDAL) has an NMAKE build file that we'd like to incorporate into our CMAKE build process.  But maybe NMAKE and CMAKE are apples and oranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea is to chain the second build system from the first.

**In CMake:**

Use something like

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nmake-target.dll
    COMMAND nmake
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Makefile
)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:add_custom_command

**In SCons:**

Use something like

`env.Command ('nmake-target.dll', null, 'nmake')`

http://scons.org/doc/2.1.0.alpha.20101125/HTML/scons-user/c3778.html

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Is this a CMAKE command?  (I'm reading the documentation but haven't found your suggestion there.)

Comment: @John `Command` is a basic builder, read here >> http://scons.org/doc/2.1.0.alpha.20101125/HTML/scons-user/c3778.html

Comment: So the main suggestion is to overwrap nmake and cmake with SCons?  That is, write a SCons script that calls the cmake parts and nmake parts as needed?  Or are you suggesting something else?